# Find coordinates of a point on a square

Tags: geometry

I have been given the following [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sLMk.png).

I've got no problem calculating the area of the square. However, I don't understand how to find points $A$ or $D$ in order to identify the equation of the line $AD$, so that I can then get the coordinates of $S$ by plugging in the $y$ value.

Furthermore, is there an equation where you can input distance, gradient & the coordinates of one point to output the coordinates of another point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I worked out the solution.

We know that the equation of the line passing through points $B$ and $C$ is $y = 3x - 12$. As both points lie on the coordinate axes, we know that $B$ is $(4,0)$ and $C$ is $(0, -12)$.

The distance between points $B$ and $C$ can be found using the equation $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$, which gives us $4\sqrt{10}$.

Now, we know the line $AB$ is perpendicular to the line $BC$ as we are told $ABCD$ is a square. Therefore, the gradient of line $AB$ is $\frac{-1}{3}$. We can use the following formula to find an equation of a line: $y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$, where $m$ stands for gradient.

Using the point $B$, we will end up with the equation $y=\frac{-x}{3}+\frac 43$. All we need to do now is plug this equation into our formula for distance, which ends up looking like: $\sqrt{(4-x)^2+[(0-(\frac{-x}{3}+\frac 43)]^2}=4\sqrt{10}$.

After solving this equation we have two $x$ coordinates, so we take the negative one which is $-8$. We input $-8$ into the equation of the line $AB$ to find the $y$ coordinate of $A$. Thus, $A$ is $(-8,4)$.

Answer (score 0):

it is easy to find the line AB since it is perpendicular to CB, you know the length of AB so you find A, than the Line parallel to CB cuts the x- Achse in S
next question: if you use vectors to describe lines  and the directionvektor a unit vector, 
in your first question you also could find A bei adding the Vektor BA to A.

Answer (score 0):

Triangles $BSA$ and $CBO$ are similar. So $BS/AB=BC/OC$.

Comment: How do we know that $\frac {BS}{AB} = \frac {BC}{OC}$ just because $\triangle BSA$ and $\triangle CBO$ are similar?

Could you also explain how this information gives us the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $S$ please?

Comment: I don't know where to start! These things are pretty obvious, I would say.

Comment: I am especially concerned that you are asking how to find the $y$-coordinate of $S$.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. Obviously, the $y$ coordinate of $S$ is $0$.

Comment: I've got the answer, although your method seems to be far more efficient. What topic does it come under, as I don't think I've learnt this?

Comment: I can see you're from the UK. I'm an A Level student btw.

Comment: Elementary Euclidean geometry. You really haven't learnt about similar triangles?

Comment: I must have, but I've forgotten. It hasn't proven to be necessary knowledge in the specification thus far. Regardless, I'll cover it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the triangle SAB and EBC are the same where E is intersection of y-axes and AB. You can easily compute the length of [EC]. After you need only make a substraction.